# How to get the n index numbers before/preceding a specific label?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, indexing

I have a dataset that looks as below; my objective is to create a list that contains the three index numbers before `Accepted`.

```
i       Label         value
0       Rejected       12
1       Rejected       10
2       Rejected       22
3       Rejected       32
4       Rejected       25
5       Rejected       15
6       Accepted       42
7       Accepted       52
8       Accepted       17
9       Accepted       8
10      Accepted       10
11      Rejected       21
12      Rejected       32
13      Rejected       12
```

The outcome for this example should be:

```
list = [3,4,5]
```

EDIT: 
This situation is repeated many times through my dataset. In some cases, the Accepted range can be only two samples like the following example:

```js
i       Label         value
0       Rejected       12
1       Rejected       10
2       Rejected       22
3       Rejected       32
4       Rejected       25
5       Rejected       15
6       Accepted       42
7       Accepted       52
8       Rejected       17
9       Rejected       8
10      Rejected       10
11      Rejected       21
12      Rejected       32
13      Rejected       12
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
df[df.Label.ne('Accepted')&df.Label.shift(-3).eq('Accepted')].index
```

---

```
Int64Index([3, 4, 5], dtype='int64', name='i')
```

Comment: @anky_91 Thank you. However, I have a question: How many indices this code can go back to? Apparently, it can go back to only short periods (less than 6 indices back). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @anky_91 Thanks for your answer, However, this is not a general solution because the Accepted range was for more than 3 .however, this won't work when you have only one or two Accepted Labels.

Comment: @AlexDavies I dont understand, can you edit the question with more details and scenarios? Thanks

Comment: I edited the question, so for the new sample, the code won't work properly. Also, your code won't work if I ask for more than three indices. (eg: like 2o previous indices) @anky_91

Answer (score 2):

You can use .loc:

```
index = df.loc[df['Label']=='Accepted', 'Label'].first_valid_index()
[index - i for i in range(1, 4)]
>> [5, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this can only work when you have one case only. In other words, if you wish to do such action more than once in your dataset, this code won't work. It will only work on the first case only.